# The Print Of A None When Itorating A List Of Objects In Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to Iterate over a list of objects, but I keep having a "None" printed after each line

```
class UserInfo():
    def __init__(self, name = str(), key = str(), ID = str()):
        self.name = name
        self.key = key
        self.ID = ID
    def info(self):
        print ("the user name is {}, the ID is {} and the key is {}".format(self.name, self.ID, self.key))

user1 = UserInfo( name = 'Mike Mourise',key = '%#^*^%#', ID = 'SVAR231G')
user2 = UserInfo( name = 'Alex Kurt',key = '%#^*^!@', ID = 'SW1I2X45')
user3 = UserInfo( name = 'Kevin Heart',key = '%@(*^%$', ID = 'BOET34617') 
users = [user1, user2, user3]

for person in users:
    print (person.info())
```

I'm want it to print this:

```
the user name is Mike Mourise, the ID is SVAR231G and the key is %#^*^%#
the user name is Alex Kurt, the ID is SW1I2X45 and the key is %#^*^!@
the user name is Kevin Heart, the ID is BOET34617 and the key is %@(*^%$
```

but it is printing this isntead:

```
the user name is Mike Mourise, the ID is SVAR231G and the key is %#^*^%#
None
the user name is Alex Kurt, the ID is SW1I2X45 and the key is %#^*^!@
None
the user name is Kevin Heart, the ID is BOET34617 and the key is %@(*^%$
None
```

please help

Comment: Your loop is printing whatever is being returned by method **info**, which is **None**. Just remove the call to **print** that surrounds the invocation of the **person.info()** method.

Comment: No, `info()` should return the formatted string instead of printing it.

Answer (score 1):

```py
# your code goes here
class UserInfo():
    def __init__(self, name , key, ID ):
        self.name = name
        self.key = key
        self.ID = ID
    def info(self):
        #use return
        return ("the user name is {}, the ID is {} and the key is {}".format(self.name, self.ID, self.key))

user1 = UserInfo( name = 'Mike Mourise',key = '%#^*^%#', ID = 'SVAR231G')
user2 = UserInfo( name = 'Alex Kurt',key = '%#^*^!@', ID = 'SW1I2X45')
user3 = UserInfo( name = 'Kevin Heart',key = '%@(*^%$', ID = 'BOET34617') 
users = [user1, user2, user3]

for person in users:
    print (person.info())
```

The reason why it printed `None` was because you never returned anything. Instead of using `print`, use `return` for the function.